# Javascript - object.offsetTop and .offsetLeft gives 0

Tags: javascript, object, offset

I'm trying to get the position of an element by using Javascript. I have used `clientTop`, `offsetHeight`, `window.getComputedStyle(box1).top` and a few things in between but all I get when I console log it is 0. The element is placed almost in the middle of the page so it should be all but 0 in the result.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <h1>Box placement</h1>

    <div id='box1' class='box center green size200'>

    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');

let browserHeight = window.innerHeight;
let browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
let boxHeight = box1.clientTop;
let boxWidth = box1.offsetLeft;

function printInfo() {                               //Result
    console.log(browserHeight);                      //1185
    console.log(browserWidth);                       //1266
    console.log(boxHeight);                          //0
    console.log(boxWidth);                           //0
    console.log(window.getComputedStyle(box1).top);  //auto
    console.log(box1.offsetLeft);                    //0
}

printInfo();
```

Any ideas to where I might have gone wrong? Here is a fiddle with the CSS as well: http://jsfiddle.net/1f23v9nj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behaviour is caused by the less.js library. If you don't really need its features, then don't include it -- problem solved.

If you *do* need it -- for reasons not apparent from the code in your question -- then wait for the `less.pageLoadFinished` promise to resolve, as follows:

```
less.pageLoadFinished.then(function () {
    'use strict';

    let box1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
    // ... etc
});
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1f23v9nj/2/)

Comment: I thought to try to learn LESS the same time but I'll pause that then... :) Brilliant fix though.